# HealthKit -> Query for workouts that have a route attached

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'd like to query `HealthKit` for all `workouts` that have a `workout-route` attached to it. Is there a way to do so with a predicate?

I got it to work by making a query to get all workouts, then one to get the routes of that workout and then an other one to get the route-data...
But this seems quite inefficient to me?!?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this? I'm struggling with the same issue but am only getting segmented location results from HealthKit queries. The answer below isn't helpful because it's only a repeat of the documentation.

Answer (score -4):

After you query the workout you need to query for the workout route and then the workout locations:

1. Ask for permission:
2. Query Workout:
3. Get the Route Sample Object:

```
let runningObjectQuery = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: myWorkout)

let routeQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: HKSeriesType.workoutRoute(), predicate: runningObjectQuery, anchor: nil, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) in
    
    guard error == nil else {
        // Handle any errors here.
        fatalError("The initial query failed.")
    }
    
    // Process the initial route data here.
}

routeQuery.updateHandler = { (query, samples, deleted, anchor, error) in
    
    guard error == nil else {
        // Handle any errors here.
        fatalError("The update failed.")
    }
    
    // Process updates or additions here.
}

store.execute(routeQuery)
```

4. Access a Route Sample’s Location Data:

```
// Create the route query.
let query = HKWorkoutRouteQuery(route: myRoute) { (query, locationsOrNil, done, errorOrNil) in
    
    // This block may be called multiple times.
    
    if let error = errorOrNil {
        // Handle any errors here.
        return
    }
    
    guard let locations = locationsOrNil else {
        fatalError("*** Invalid State: This can only fail if there was an error. ***")
    }
    
    // Do something with this batch of location data.
        
    if done {
        // The query returned all the location data associated with the route.
        // Do something with the complete data set.
    }
    
    // You can stop the query by calling:
    // store.stop(query)
    
}
store.execute(query)
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/reading_route_data

Comment: This is only a repeat of the documentation, can you provide any insight on how to fill out the route query code to add location data to a map?